# How to change back a line during file read

Tags: python, io, line

In my code I have a line length print like this:

```
line = file.readline()
print("length = ", len(line))
```

after that I start to scan the lines by doing this:

```
for i in range(len(line)):
        if(file.read(1) == 'b'):
            print("letter 'b' found.")
```

The problem is that the `for` loop starts reading on line 2 of the file.
How can I make it start reading at line 1 without closing and reopening the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use `file.seek`  to move the position of the next read, but that's inefficient. You've already read in the line, so you can just process
`line` without having to read it in a second time.

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    print("length = ", len(line))
    if 'b' in line:
        print("letter 'b' found.")

    for line in f: 
    ...
```

Comment: @Dieseltjuh: If you need to process the first line in a special way, use `readline`, process the first line specially, then loop over the rest of the file. If you want to process all lines in the same way, then don't use `readline`. I hope this helps clarify.

Comment: Rather than `readline`, you could do `line = next(f)` (or `f.next()` depending on Python version).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to handle the first line specially.

```
lineno = 1
found = False
for line in file:
    if 'b' in line:
        found = True

    if lineno == 1:
        print("length of first line: %d" % len(line))
    lineno += 1

if found:
    print("letter 'b' found.")
```

Comment: This is not very well thought out. You can just treat the first line separately using `next` rather than testing and incrementing `lineno` in every iteration. Also, `file` is a built-in for Python, don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: @Seth the `next` way would skip 'b' in the first line. The question is very unclear, and my answer was a guess: that the OP needs to treat the first line specially, printing its length, and simultaneously checking whether *whole file* contains letter 'b'.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for character in line:
            if character == "b":
                print "letter 'b' found."
```

or if you just need the number:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    b = sum(1 for line in f for char in line if char == "b")
print "found %d b" % b
```

Comment: You don't need to loop entire string to search for a character. `'b' in string` does it.

Comment: @ulidtko: I'm not trying to search for it, I'm trying to count the number of occurrences. `'b' in string` gives `True` for `bbbbbb`, `sum(char == "b" for char in line)` gives `6`.

Comment: I was talking about the first code snippet. `for character in line: if character == "b": ...` can be simplified to `if "b" in line: ...`.

Comment: @ulidtko: ok, but there, it would print "letter 'b' found" once per line instead of (number of b's) time per line, which is what the OP's code asks for.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! usr/bin/env python

#Open the file , i assumed its called somefile.txt
file = open('somefile.txt.txt','r')
#Lets loop through the lines ... 
for line in file.readlines():
    #test if letter 'b' is in each line ... 
    if 'b' in line: 
        #print that we found a b in the line
        print  "letter b found"
```